# Не работает функция reversed() для списка,который является полем класса

Tags: python, ооп, функции

Есть класс реализации стека, мне нужно поменять информацию находящуюся в 2 стеках между собой. Но по определению стека я не могу просто переприсвоить значения,я использовал функцию reversed() для записи данных стека в буферный стек,а в выводе видно что информация в буферном стеке записана так же как и в основном.

```
firstS = Stack()
secondS = Stack()     # Создание объектов класа Stack
for i in range(0, 5):
    firstS.push(0 + i)     # Заполнение первого

for i in range(0, 5):
    secondS.push(100 + i)  # Заполнение второго

buffArrayfirst = Stack()
buffArraysecond = Stack()   # Буферные объекты для временного хранения данных

for item in reversed(firstS.items):  # Не работает!!!
    buffArrayfirst.push(item)

for i in buffArrayfirst.items:
    print(buffArrayfirst.items[i])
```

Comment: Добавьте определение класса `Stack`

Comment: `reversed` работает для объектов, имеющих метод `__reversed__`, или поддерживающих sequence протокол (поддерживают итерацию по целочисленному индексу начиная с 0, и имеющих метод `__len__`) (см. [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)). Если `Stack.items` - это например просто итератор, то функция `reversed` к нему не применима.

Comment: что значит "не работает"? Что вы ожидали получить (конкретный результат), что вместо этого происходит? Создайте минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, который проблему демонстрирует [mcve].  Подсказка: reversed() не знает имени объекта списка, под которым вы его передали: результат от имени не зависит—для одного и того же списка, как бы он не назывался, вы получите один и тот же ответ.